# WSO2 Developer studio keeps removing gov endpoints in send mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I'm using endpoints which are stored in governance registry so I often use code like this:

```
<send>
<endpoint key="gov:endpoints/policyEp.xml"/>
</send>
```

unfortunately, once in a while, my endpoint disappears, leaving empty send tag :( It usually happens when saving changes to the proxy or rebuilding cars to deploy on attached carbon server (in developer studio 3.8.0).

I have searched for similar issues and found none. Any ideas?

I have a suspicion that it has something to do with developer studio's validation mechanism because i haven't found a way to create such code from the designer and I think that this validation mechanism assumes that it is not possible.

Maybe there is away to disable develop studio's sequence validation all together?

Comment: Seems this is a known bug https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-3283

Comment: Thank you, i could not find these issue on jira :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. A workaround is Always open that sequence or proxy with `XML Editor`by `Right click` options. It happens when you try to open that artifact in Design view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to suspend all validators:

**Window>Preferences>Validation>Suspend all validators**

Att;

Vitor Darela de Oliveira

Comment: It doesn't help... I guess we just need to wait for new Developer Studio :)

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2460) has been resolved in WSO2 Integration Studio 6.5.0 release.