# Developer Studio 6.5. Design view removing endpoint

Tags: xml, wso2

It happens when you try to open that artifact in Design view.

1. Design view working slowly (how can be faster?)
2. Design view remove all endpoints from services (not, when opened by XML)
3. Design view have error on comments `<!--  -->`

that problem was on
[WSO2 Developer studio keeps removing gov endpoints in send mediator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045554/wso2-developer-studio-keeps-removing-gov-endpoints-in-send-mediator)

and this problem have a Studio 6.5.0

```
<send>
<endpoint>
<http method="post" uri-template="http://{uri.var.serverhost}:8280/services/declaration.SOAP12Endpoint"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
```

1. In car file I see `<send/>` (when Studio compiled project)
2. When I edit code in XML format, save changes, close code - it's good. But when I opening this code in Design view and close code - it removes all endpoints

recommendation "Window>Preferences>Validation>Suspend all validators" is not working.
How can to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In resource of API can use:

```
<endpoint key="name_of_endpoint"/>
```

And add endpoint into project of API...